# tile provider and API 23 permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, osmdroid

I have a problem with the API 23 permissions and notably the storage permission:
After I ask the user for the permission and get the answers, I call the `setTileSource()` method but strangely, I only get a blue map as if the tile system didn't have the storage access.
I can create a folder between the permissions mechanism and the mapView initialisation without any problem. 
If I put the application in background and back in foreground, the tiles are displayed.

I didn't see anything special about that in the sample application so I don't understand what happens here.

Any idea?

Comment: Just conjecture but it sounds like you need to call some sort of `Refresh` method or something like that. Sounds like the current context doesn't know it has permissions yet. Once you background and foreground the app it refreshes and has permissions and executes properly.

Comment: @amza, sure, but I do the same to in both cases, if I need to ask for permission, mapview initialisation is just delayed. for example, next time I start the application, I see that I have all permissions granted and I display the map perfectly. So, the first time I execute the app, I don't see why osmdroid couldn't have access to the storage to write the pngs as I can write in it myself before initializing mapview.

Answer (score 1):

If your startup activity contains the `MapView` in the layout file, the map will inflate and initialize when you load the layout file. If you ask for permissions before the layout file is initialized, it may fix the problem for you.

Or restart the activity after the user has granted permissions

Or have a simple startup activity that prompts, then loads the map activity.

Or programmatically construct the mapview and attach it after the permission is granted

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem the permission of localisation

Comment: Could you add details to your answer?